# QMS basemap opening up in wrong CRS and GPS points (maybe?) showing in wrong place

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-2.18, quickmapservices

Im having problems with the CRS of my QMS basemap in Qgis (2.18).

As a basemap im using the ESRI satellite provided by the QMS plugin. I have set my default and project CRS to WGS 84/UTM zone 19S (EPSG: 32719), and this is the CRS i want to use in my maps. But when i open the layers (ESRI satellite and my gps points as shp.) everything seems correct, but in properties i can see that the ESRI satellite have opened up in Pseudo Mercator (EPSG: 3857). Anyhow, the ESRI satellite does not look like Pseudo Mercator, it looks like this:
[image]

So, my layers have different CRS but the gps points show in right location, at least approximately. I changed the CRS of ESRI satellite to WGS 84/UTM zone 19S, but then when both layers have the same CRS my gps points show in the middle of the Nort Sea, so in the other side of the world.

Is it possible that only the name of the CRS of ESRI satellite in properties is showing wrong?

I also tried changing the CRS of the shapefile, so that both layers would be in Pseudo Mercator, but again the gps points show in the North Sea.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ESRI satellite image actually *is* in EPSG: 3857. That's not a problem, just make sure you have "on-the-fly reprojection" turned on in the project properties. QGIS will re-project the satellite image into your chosen project CRS.

*Don't* change the CRS of either layer in the layer properties. This forces QGIS to interpret the layer as though it was in the CRS you chose. Since it's actually in a different CRS, the layer will be incorrectly displayed.